# grunt svg sprite - space between icons

Tags: svg, gruntjs

i'm using [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-svg-sprite) to create svg sprites for my site.
the plugin works as expected and also the css file.

but, the svg file that was created, certain icons appear clipped or too close to the next icon and i can see one pixel from the other image.

i tried using spacing:

```
spacing: {         
     padding : 10
}
```

but the padding is added to the image width and height and i don't want the images to get bigger.

Comment: Imagine, this is still a bug. I just discovered it for Firefox if windows scaling is 125% which is the recommended. I submitted an issue on their issue tracker, but last release is 3 years ago, i don't know if it will ever be fixed.

Comment: What i've done for now is increase the viewport size of my svg's. So icons with height and width 16 and viewport was 0 0 16 16, i increase viewport to 0 0 18 18, that seems to add enough space to not spill across icons.